# Service httpd error

Tags: linux, dns, centos, apache

I have a centOS virtual machine with 3 virtual hosts. It worked fine until this moment when I lost access to the dns server. Now the hosts can't be resolved. Can any1 tell me if I can configure some static routes or something to the virtual hosts?

Print screen with the httpd response:
[image]

P.S. I would prefere not to configure a DNS server since the old one will start tomorrow again.

Comment: If all you need is a temporary solution to resolve hostnames to IPs, add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file. That said, this question is probably more suitable for http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `/etc/hosts` you can map IP addresses to hostnames:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 example.net
// etc...
```

Comment: I tried. 127.0.0.1 virtualhost1.something.something. It sends me to the apache test page instead of my page. Also the httpd gives me the same errors at restart.

Comment: @zozo You'd have to adjust the IP address, of course. Use your IP from the screenshot (`192.168.1.9`) or whatever address that couldn't be resolved.