# Apache (xampp) doesn't work when I change ServerName in VirtualHost

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

**The issue:**

Everything works fine all until I change the name of 'dev' into anything else, i.e.'devo'.
Error logs say s'could not resolve host name'. The 'dev' site is done with PHP Symfony.

**What I tried doing:**

- Someone before has setup it up, so I removed everything, and copied over the project again, reinstalled XAMPP, rewrote the vhosts file, but the issue remained.
- I checked my Firefox and IE settings and there's no special rules in LAN settings.
- I tried clearing my browsers cache.

**My Question is: How can a change of hostname screw everything up?**

Contents of my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost dev:80>
  ServerName dev
  DocumentRoot "C:\workspace\trunk\web"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814515/service-httpd-error/4814570#4814570).

Although for you, it's `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

I guess your machine's name is `dev` and can hence be resolved. Any other hostname (or `ServerName` for that matter) needs to show up in the `hosts` file so it can be resolved to an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

What about names resolution (check your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29))? Does your pc ping devo to localhost?
Anyway, you can also use ServerAlias to specify more than one name for a specific installation.

Comment: `ServerAlias` only resolves the issue of Apache croaking. It still doesn't resolve when you're trying to go to `http://devo/`.

Comment: Yes, it was not written as answer but maybe could be a new useful information. The point was hosts, of course.